# Using ggplot to plot cumsum of two separate factors

Tags: r, ggplot2, cumsum

Using the following data I need to plot cumulative curves for factors "in" and "out.

```
years <- c(1969, 1972, 1974, 1975, 1975, 1976, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1978, 1979, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1983, 1984, 1984, 1985, 1985, 1986, 1986, 1987, 1987, 1988, 1988, 1989, 1989, 1990, 1990, 1991, 1991, 1992)
places <- c("in","out","out","in","out","in","out","out","in","out","in",     "out","out","in","out","out","in","out","in","out","in","out","in", "out","in","out","in","out","in","out","in","out","in","out","in")   
count <- c(1,2,1,1,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,1,7,4,4,5,1,3,5,3,4,6,7,3,2,6,4,3,6,11,5, 7,9)

peryear <- data.frame(years,places,count)
```

If I plot using

```
ggplot(peryear %>% filter(places=="in"),aes(x=years,y=cumsum(count))) + geom_point()+geom_line()
ggplot(peryear %>% filter(places=="out"),aes(x=years,y=cumsum(count))) + geom_point()+geom_line()
```

I get what I expected:

[image: cumsum of "in"]
[image: cumsum of "out"]

However, when I tried to use ggplot2 with

```
ggplot(peryear,aes(x=years,y=cumsum(count),color=places)) + geom_line()+geom_point()
```

I got the following wrong plot:

[image: wrong cumsum ggplot]

I believe this plot is wrong because the curves for both places are reaching values higher than 100 whereas for individual plots they get up to around 70.

How can I use ggplot2 to plot cumsum curves of my data?

Comment: I answered but then I realized I wasn't sure what you're looking for. The first two plots aren't `cumsum`, the third one probably is, so what exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: `?stat_function()` might be useful here

Comment: First two plots are definitely not cumsum - you are simply plotting the counts, not their cumulative sum: each ggplot statement has aesthetic aes(x=years,y=count). Third plot looks like a cumulative sum to me. What's the problem?

Comment: I have fixed my first and second plots now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That last graph is close to what you want, but the cumulative sum lines seem too close to each other. Here's one way to approach it:

```
ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x=years,y=cumsum(count),colour='red'),peryear %>% filter(places=='in')) +
    geom_line(aes(x=years,y=cumsum(count), colour='navy'),peryear %>% filter(places=='out')) +
    scale_colour_discrete(name  = 'places',
                  labels=c("in", "out"))
```

[image]